# VirtualBox GPU Passthrough: Code 12 in guest

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I've stubbed out and passed a secondary GeForce 8400GS PCI card to my (working) Windows 7 Guest.  The guest reports the error

```
This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. (Code 12)

If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the other devices on this system.`
```

I have skimmed quite a few PCI passthrough tutorials, but they all basically come down to associating the PCI device with pci-stub.  None of them seem to specifically address using passthrough to provide a hardware GPU to a VirtualBox Windows guest.  Here's the output of `lspci -k`.  It seems to be the same both before and after the VM is running.

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Device 196e:0879
    Kernel driver in use: pci-stub
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_367, nvidia_367_drm
05:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Device 196e:0879
    Kernel driver in use: pci-stub
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

How can I figure out what's preventing this GPU from being enabled in the guest?  Do I have to do a fresh install with the PCI card already attached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have come down to my specific hardware (an ancient PCI 8400GS) not being capable of being an active VGA passthrough device while there is an active Virtual Display.

NB that I've only tried it with QXL -- others might not cause conflicts.